# Missing geometry and UVs when batch rendering through command line and Deadline

Tags: rendering, command-line

I'm trying to render a scene composed of alembics(cached geometry and transformations) on my farm using deadline, which should itself be using command line rendering anyways. When I try to command line render the scene on windows either via the command prompt or deadline, it messes up some frames, more often than not it renders a good frame and then a bad one, where the geometry disappears and uv's get messed up.

I am using Blender 2.81 on Windows 10.

any light that you can shed on why this is and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.

I'll attach a sample of a good and a bad frame;

[image: Good frame]

[image: Bad frame]

Comment: Looks like it is a disk mapping problem, I changed all paths(textures, files) to the mapped disk of my server and seems to work fine.